# C - tokenizing from scanf

Tags: c, token

I want to tokenize whatever string the user inputs. My code is this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
int main(void)
{
    char str;
    char *token;

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    scanf("%s\n", &str);

    token = strtok(&str, " ,.-");

    while(token != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s\n", token);

        token = strtok(NULL, " ,.-");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

but if I input a string like 'dogs are brown' it will only return 'dogs'. How can I get it to return each word in the string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Oh this isn't good. You only allocated one byte for your string (`char str;` is one byte). So you're overwriting your stack when you call `scanf`. You need to declare an array, (*e.g.*, `char str[200];` for 200 bytes in this case - or however large you want it within reason), and then call `scanf("%s\n", str);` and `strtok(str, " ,.-");`. It doesn't get rid of the problem you're reporting, but it keeps your code from doing bad things.

Comment: @lurker ah, I see now. Is there a size allocation that will automatically accommodate to the size of the string the user inputs?

Comment: You could try `getline(3)`.

Comment: The `scanf("%s\n"...)` is only going to scan up to the blank (see the manual page for `scanf`) so it's just reading one word to start with.

Comment: Read the line with `fgets()` and use `token = strtok(..., " ,.-\n");`

Comment: @chux I am not reading from a file, so how can I use fgets()?

Comment: `char buf[100]; fgets(buf, sizeof buf, stdin)`

Answer (score 0):

Along with **lurker**'s comment I will say that after you have `char str[200]` you have to get a line at once.Use `getline`.

Alternatively as `gets` is avoided you may use `fgets`to read a line in string.

Comment: use getline in place of scanf?

Comment: @donutjuice.:otherwise how will you get the space seperated words in a string..?

Comment: I am getting an undefined reference to getline()

Comment: `getline()` is a common function, yet not part of the C standard library - may not be available.

Comment: @donutjuice.: ALternatively fgets can be used...that also works

Comment: @ameyCU.: Yes I have added that part...Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are almost there but when you write

```
char str;
```

you only have space to store 1 character, the strtok function takes a string as argument and then modifies that string chopping it up into pieces.

In order for you to do that you need to provide space for the string

```
char str[64];
```

A string in C is a series of characters followed by a terminating 0 value so declaring it with 64 means you can enter a string with max 63 characters. In order to prevent a user from entering longer strings you could use another function like fgets to read from the keyboard.

```
fgets( str, sizeof(str), stdin );
```

then apply your strtok calls.

Comment: Also need to add `'\n'` to `" ,.-"` or somehow account for the `'\n'` should code use `fgets()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
scanf("%s\n", str);
```

correct way to input str. Remove '&'.

also , please declare `char str` to `char str[200]` as you are inputting string

Comment: its should be str[100]